# ¿Porque una función de php me modifica la cadena de SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, pdo, email

Tengo un codigo de php que es el siguiente:

`$model->LogIn('juanberesiarte@gmail.com', 'hola');`
El cual llama a una función llamada LogIn, ahora, este es el codigo que esta dentro de esa función:

```
public function LogIn($email, $password){

        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email=" . $email);

        print_r($this->db->registros());

}
```

El problema esta en que, yo le paso mi gmail como variable, pero a la hora de concatenarlo se borra todo execpto lo que va después de la arroba. Osea, en ves de buscar "juanberesiarte@gmail.com" busca "@gmail.com" y no se como solucionarlo.

Pequeños detalles, estoy trabajando con PDO. Este es el codigo de cada función a las que llame antes:

```
public function query($sql){

        $this->stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
}
```

en donde $this->connect contiene la conexion a la base de datos.

```
public function registros(){

        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

en la cual la función de execute() simplemente retorna la función execute de la conección guardada en la variable stmt.

Por si no se me entendio un carajo:

Archivo que se conecta a la base de datos:

```
class DataBase{

    // Declaro datos de la base de datos
    private $name = DB_NAME;
    private $usuario = DB_USER;
    private $password = DB_PASSWORD;
    private $host = DB_HOST;

    // declaro variables para uso de llamadas sql
    protected $connect;
    protected $stmt;
    protected $error;

    public function __construct(){

        // Funcion para conectar mediante la clase
        $sdn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->name;
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        try {

            $this->connect = new PDO($sdn, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, $options);
            $this->connect->exec('set names utf8');

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            echo $this->error;
        }
    }

    public function query($sql){

        $this->stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type=PDO::PARAM_STR){

        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute(){

        return $this->stmt->execute();      
    }

    public function registros(){

        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function close(){

        $this->connect = null;
    }
}
```

Modelo que utiliza esta conección:

```
class LoginModel {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db = new DataBase;
    }

    public function LogIn($email, $password){

        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email=" . $email);

        print_r($this->db->registros());

}
```

Y la función que llama al modelo:

```
function index(){
        $this->vista('content/login');
        $model = $this->modelo('LoginModel');
        $model->LogIn('juanberesiarte@gmail.com', 'hola');
    }
```

Y bueno, si pueden ayudarme con esto estaré agradecido, porque llevo rompiendome la cabeza varias con esto.

Y de paso les dejo el error que se imprime en pantalla:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/librerias/DataBase.php:46 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/librerias/DataBase.php(46): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/librerias/DataBase.php(51): DataBase->execute() #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/models/LoginModel.php(16): DataBase->registros() #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/controllers/login.php(10): LoginModel->LogIn('juanberesiarte@...', 'hola') #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/librerias/Core.php(42): login->index() #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/public/index.php(6): Core->__construct() #6 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/app/librerias/DataBase.php on line 46

Answer (score 0):

Puedo equivocarme porque hace mucho no toco PHP, pero es probable que la comparación en la consulta SQL deba ser contra una cadena y no estás marcándola como tal. Una consulta normalita sería algo como `SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE login = 'pepito@gmail.com';`. Notarás los identificadores de cadena (de string, pues).

Así nada más, el motor lo puede interpretar como una tabla remota, por ejemplo. Buscará la a pepito como otra tabla, otro recurso y @gmail.com como un origen de datos, no lo sé con certeza (porque no sé en qué va el uso de ese carácter en MySQL)

Prueba armando la consulta con algo como

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email='" . $email . "'");
```

Comment: Acertado, aunque lo más correcto sería utilizar el método `bindValue` para evitar vulnerabilidades de tipo inyección SQL

Comment: @BaruchSpinoza eso es verdad, aprovechar por completo PDO. Podrías proponer la respuesta completa y adecuada, yo votaría por ella. De nuevo, mi PHP está oxidado :)

Answer (score 0):

Es importante usar la función bindValue de PDO para evitar vulnerabilidades SQL.

Esto también evita posibles errores de sintaxis como el que estás experimentando.

```php
<?php
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email = :correo");
$this->db->bind(':correo', 'juanberesiarte@gmail.com');
```